# TCMalloc Allocator for STL

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management, allocator, tcmalloc

I want to use TCMalloc with STL containers, so I need an allocator built with TCMalloc (like tbb_allocator with TBB malloc). I cannot find any anything [TCMalloc documentation](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html) (if it is called a documentation). So I start to explore the header files and find a class called `STL_Allocator`. But something is not clear to me. Quotation from stl_allocator.h :

```
// Generic allocator class for STL objects
// that uses a given type-less allocator Alloc, which must provide:
//   static void* Alloc::Allocate(size_t size);
//   static void Alloc::Free(void* ptr, size_t size);
//
// STL_Allocator<T, MyAlloc> provides the same thread-safety
// guarantees as MyAlloc.
//
// Usage example:
//   set<T, less<T>, STL_Allocator<T, MyAlloc> > my_set;
// CAVEAT: Parts of the code below are probably specific
//         to the STL version(s) we are using.
//         The code is simply lifted from what std::allocator<> provides.
```

And the definition of STL_Allocator template class is:

```
template <typename T, class Alloc>
class STL_Allocator {
//...
}
```

I have no idea what that `Alloc` argument could be. Am I supposed to write a wrapper class for some memory allocation functions? Anyone used TCMalloc?

Answer (score 8):

The `STL_Allocator` class in TCMalloc is an adapter class: you
instanciate it with a (simpler) *Alloc* class providing `Allocate` and
`Free` methods as in the comment you quoted, and -voila- you get a
class that implements all the requirements for an 
[STL allocator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/allocator.aspx) (follow the link for an introductory article on
what STL allocators are and how to implement one).

Examples of use include the `simple_alloc` class that [Null Set](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556528/null-set)
drafted in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292994/tcmalloc-allocator-for-stl/5293848#5293848), but there's an example in the TCMalloc
sources: the `MyAllocator` class in file [memory_region_map.h](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/memory_region_map.h).

Note, however, that the header file defining `STL_Allocator` is an
*internal* one and is not installed as part of the public include
files of the TCMalloc library.

That said, please note that there is no need to use a custom allocator
to benefit from TCMalloc in C++ code: if the standard allocator uses
malloc() at some point, you just need to preload or link with TCMalloc
and that's it.  If you are using the GNU C++ compiler, you can [`#include
<ext/malloc_allocator.h>`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/malloc__allocator_8h-source.html) to use an allocator that simply wraps
malloc() with no extra logic.

Comment: I am afraid I am using MSVC and replacing `malloc` is hard task. Also I need fast allocation of just two classes in my application, even for one of them placement new `new (tcmalloc::alloc()) ClassNAme()` will do perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will work, but try this simple wrap of malloc and free.

```
#include <cstdlib.h>

struct simple_alloc {
    static void* Allocate(size_t size){
        return malloc(size);
    }
    static void Free(void* ptr, size_t size){
        free(ptr);
    }
}
```